# Why my sparse tensor cannot convert to Tensor ?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I want to feed my sparse data to Tensorflow by batch, so I use these code:

```
with graph.as_default():
    global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
    # Here we use the indices and values to reproduce the input SparseTensor
    sp_indice = tf.placeholder(tf.int64)
    sp_value = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    x =  tf.SparseTensor(sp_indice, sp_value, [batch_size, feature_num])
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder("float32")
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([feature_num, 1]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

    # Construct model
    pred = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b) # Softmax
    # Minimize error using cross entropy
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y*tf.log(pred), reduction_indices=1))
```

But I got an error:

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor'> to Tensor. Contents: SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("Placeholder:0", dtype=int64), values=Tensor("Placeholder_1:0", dtype=float32), dense_shape=Tensor("SparseTensor/dense_shape:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int64)). Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

I am confused about this error, it seems like my `sp_indice = tf.placeholder(tf.int64)` was wrong, maybe because I did not give the `shape`.  But I cannot make sure the shape since the shape is different in every batch. How can I deliver index array and value array to the tensor?

Answer (score 3):

When you are doing matrix multiplication of a sparse tensor, you need to use [`tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_tensor_dense_matmul).

```
pred = tf.nn.softmax(tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(x, W) + b)
```